# how to use sort_index with specific order in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use sort_index to sort value_counts()

The df I have is like this

```
   a
1 low
2 high
3 vhigh
...
```

I want to counts columns a and sort them by index of low,med,high,vhigh

> ```
> df['a'].value_counts()
> med   20
> high  30
> low   10
> vhigh 15
> ```

If I add sort_index,it will be like this

> ```
> high  30
> low   10
> med   20
> vhigh 15
> ```

That's what I want

> ```
> low   10
> med   20
> high  30
> vhigh 15
> ```

Comment: value_counts by default it will be sort by value in descending order. I think your sample output is not correct. provide the actual data frame

Comment: I didn't use sort_index at sample, if I add it. the result will be sort in descending, but it still not the answer what am I expecting

Comment: why is `vhigh 15` at the bottom?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given the question, this has to be a custom sorting problem -

```
   value  counts
0    med      20
1   high      30
2    low      10
3  vhigh      15
```

This is the `df` you get when you do a `value_counts()`

Define the `value` field as a `pd.Categorical` and define the order -

```
df['value'] = pd.Categorical(df['value'], ["low", "med", "high", "vhigh"])
```

Then do a sort -

```
df.sort_values('value')
```

**Output**

```
   value  counts
2    low      10
0    med      20
1   high      30
3  vhigh      15
```

Comment: Thanks, but acually low,med,high,vhigh is the value of one columns

Comment: @Haliris yes, do this to the output of the `value_counts()` output dataframe

Comment: Thanks. This is very useful for my application too. Interestingly, you didn't need to pass `ordered=True` when using `pd.Categorical()` for this to work. I wonder why.